# the parameter cannot have a value of null because of its type when declaring variable

Tags: flutter

I'm really new in Flutter.
I try to declare a variable, in a video tutorial seems no error occured, but when I try to do myself, an error occured like this

"the parameter cannot have a value of null because of its type but the implicit default value is null"

Here's my code :

```
class CardSaya extends StatelessWidget {
CardSaya ({this.icon, this.teks});

final IconData icon;
final String teks;
```

The `redline` shows on "icon" and "teks"

Can you tell me what's wrong on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tutorial which you show is flutter without null safety, you can read more about that [here](https://proxify.io/articles/flutter-2-null-safety). and hence it is showing you error,

you can do two things:

1. downgrade flutter version in pubspec.yaml

   ```
   environment:
     sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"   <--- here you can use any below 2.11.0
   ```
2. Update code to follow null safety

   ```
   class CardSaya extends StatelessWidget {
   CardSaya ({required this.icon,required this.teks});

   final IconData icon;
   final String teks;
   ```